# $(E-A)$ and $(E+A)^{-1}$ commute

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $E$ is the identity matrix and $A$ is an orthogonal matrix, and that $E+A$ is invertible. Prove:

1)$(E-A)$ and $(E+A)^{-1}$ commute

2)$(E-A)(E+A)^{-1}$ is an anti-symmetric matrix.

My attempted solution:

> A is 0 matrix/ or Det(A)=1?

---

For2 there is a wrong deduction

\begin{align}\left[(E-A)(E+A)^{-1}\right]^t=\left((E+A)^{-1}\right)^t(E-A)^t=(E+A)^{-1}(E-A)=(E-A)(E+A)^{-1}\end{align}

Where is the $-1$?

Comment: In 1), is it $E-A$ and $(E+A)^{-1}$ commute? You have $X^{-1}X = E = XX^{-1}$ for all invertible $X$, so as written, 1) isn't nontrivial at all.

Comment: If $A$ is orthogonal, $\det(A)=\pm 1$ and cannot be zero matrix.

Comment: @hardmath yes, you're right.

Comment: $E$ is any matrix?

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen $E$ is identity matrix I think.

Comment: Then why not call it $I$ (or possibly $1$) as most people do?

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen fine, I just obey/inherit that from my text.

Comment: A note on terminology: An operation can be commutative, while elements can commute.

Comment: I don't understand "A is 0 matrix/ or Det(A)=1?". Is this an attempted solution?

Comment: @VedranŠego yes, my tries

Comment: @VedranŠego Hi, see my edit, do you know where goes wrong?

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Hi, see my edit, do you know where goes wrong?

Comment: @integer This is wrong: $\left((E+A)^{-1}\right)^t(E-A)^t=(E+A)^{-1}(E-A)$ because $A$ is orthogonal, not symmetric.

Comment: @VedranŠego ah, yes, you're right. thanks,

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: For (1) note, that by direct computation 
$$ (E+A)(E-A) = E - A^2 = (E-A)(E+A)$$
now multiply wisely by $(E+A)^{-1}$.

For (2), we have to prove
$$ \bigl( (E+A)^{-1}(E-A)\bigr)^t = -(E-A)(E+A)^{-1} \iff 
   (E-A^t)(E+A) = -(E+A^t)(E-A) $$

Comment: Hi, for (2) I haven't understood now, can you give me some words and where is $-1$ comes from? I've added a wrong deduction, where goes wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ commute and that $X$ is inversible. **Automatically**, this implies that  $X^{-1}$ and $Y$ commute because
$$YX^{-1} = (X^{-1} X) Y X^{-1}= X^{-1}(YX)X^{-1} = X^{-1}Y(XX^{-1}) = X^{-1}Y.$$
Here, is obvious that $X = E+A$ and $Y = E-A$ commute because they are polynomials of $A$. You can also check directly that $(E+A)(E-A) = E - A^2 = (E-A)(E+A)$.

Answer (score 0):

1. Note that by Cayley-Hamilton theorem, $(E+A)^{-1}$ is a polynomial in $E+A$ and therefore also a polynomial in $A$. Since polynomials in $A$ commute, $(E+A)^{-1}$ commutes with $E-A$, **regardless of whether $A$ is orthogonal or not**.
2. In your proof attempt, you wrote $\left((E+A)^{-1}\right)^t(E-A)^t=(E+A)^{-1}(E-A)$ without justifying it. Actually, since $A$ is orthogonal, we have $A^tA=AA^t=I$ and hence you should have
   \begin{align*}
   \left((E+A)^{-1}\right)^t(\color{red}{E-A})^t
   &=(E+A^t)^{-1}(E-A)^t\\
   &=\left(A^t(A+E)\right)^{-1}\left(\color{red}{(A^t-E)A}\right)^t.
   \end{align*}
   You may continue your proof from here. Note that, by pulling out $A$ from $E-A$ in the above, we produce the difference $A^t-E$. Taking transpose, we get $A-E$ and this is the source of $-1$.

As a remark, the mapping $A\mapsto(E+A)^{-1}(E-A)$ is known as the [Cayley transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_transform).